# How to replace an image in cloudinary and keep the same URL?

Tags: image-manipulation, cloudinary

I have an image in cloudinary that I would like to replace but keep the original URL. Would it be possible?

Comment: You should check out [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io). What you have asked is fairly easy with a global setting. Do check our plans, you will love it.
Disclaimer: I am the co-founder.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to update an image and keep the same URL.

When you upload the new image you want to make its public_id be the same as the existing image you're trying to replace. Then your Cloudinary account will be updated with the new image overriding the old one.

However note that if the original (older) image was already accessed, it might get cached in the CDN.

Here is a helpful article for further reading on how to update already existing images and how you can invalidate your resources on the CDN if need be:

https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520852-How-can-I-update-an-already-uploaded-image-

Comment: Thank you, but how to do exactly this part:  "When you upload the new image you want to make its public_id be the same as the existing image you're trying to replace"

Comment: You can do so by uploading the new image in the Media Library and giving it the same public id as the old image. This should ask you if you want to overwrite the image. 

You can also use the upload API and specify the public id in the upload as follows (here is a Ruby example):
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(filename, options = {public_id: "insert_here"})
This will replace the old image upon upload.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but I don't have the rep.

Things might have changed in the UI that make Marissa's answer slightly inaccurate (at least for doing it thr.  When I attempted to create a new image with the same public ID, it didn't ask me to overwrite the old one, it just gave it the public ID I submitted and appended it with "-1".

In order to create a new image at the same URL as I had it previously, I had to delete the old image, log out and log back in to cloudinary, and then create a new image with the same public ID (the public ID option appears if you click on advanced at the bottom of the upload window).

Just remember you need to delete the version from the URL ( "/vXXXXXX" where X is a number).

Comment: I just tested uploading an image to my account from the Media library with the same name as already existing name and it asked me whether or not I want to replace the original image. Are you using any upload preset? Cloudinary adds random string suffix if a public id already exists in the account and not number.