# Can we update uploaded image on cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm new to use cloudinary service.
Uploaded image successfully on cloudinary and get public URL.
But I want to update existing image with new one is there any option on cloudinary to update existing image?
Please suggest me in this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969981/how-to-replace-an-image-in-cloudinary-and-keep-the-same-url

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to update an asset already uploaded into Cloudinary.

To do that, you would need to perform an [upload()](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) method call and supply the new asset you want to upload (in the `file` parameter) and also set the `public_id` parameter to the existing `public_id` you want to overwrite. The `overwrite` parameter as part of the `upload()` method already defaults to `True` and that will be all that's needed to replace the old asset in your account with the new one. You should also consider passing the `invalidate` parameter set to `True` to tell Cloudinary to purge the CDN cache for the old asset so that existing URLs return the new asset after the update.

Apart from the API, you can overwrite the image via Media Library UI upload as well. To do that you would need to go to your Media Library and use the Upload button to launch the Upload Widget. There you will see an 'Advanced' option at the bottom that will allow you to specify a `public_id` which you would set to the public_id you want to overwrite and then just drag and drop or select the asset you want to upload. You will get a prompt to confirm the overwrite action before the upload completes.

Answer (score 0):

Click on upload and then click on advanced settings.
Then enter public id same as image you want to replace.
This will update the image with new version id.
[Screenshot of uploading with advanced settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUrEm.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a catch in using the [upload()](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload) function to update the existing image or file:

> if you provide a wrong a `public_id` that doesn't exist in your cloudinary storage then the upload method will **create a new file** with wrong [The public_id that doesn't exist] `public_id`.

So to update the existing file, I would like to prefer first destroy the file with the help of [destroy()](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy) then upload it again.
**Note :** distroy function always resolve if it can't find the file then it will return `{ result: 'not found' }` else if it successfully deleted the file then it will return `{ result: 'ok' }`.

> Step 1. Destroy the image with the help of public_id

```
const { result } = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(public_id);
if (result === "not found")
  throw new BadRequestError("Please provide correct public_id");
if (result !== "ok")
  throw new Error("Try again later.");
});
```

> Step 2. Upload it again.

```
const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(avatar.url, {
    public_id: avatar.public_id,
  });
  console.log(myCloud);
```

If anyone knows other better solution then please share!!
*Thank you*

Answer (score 0):

```js
const imageUpdater = async (imagePublicId, imagePath) => {
    try {
        const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(imagePath, {
            public_id: imagePublicId,
        })
        return result
    } catch (error) {
        throw new AppError(
            StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST,
            "Cannot update image. Please try again."
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.