# Updating avatars in posts - MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern, cloudinary

I'm trying to create a social media web application through the MERN stack, and I want avatars to be shown in each of the user's posts. Intuitively, I will have an avatar field of the post model which will store the URL of the owner's avatar which is hosted in cloudinary. However, if a user changes their avatar, my first thought would be to change all of the url in all of their posts which is obviously expensive. I just wanna know if there are best practices for this scenario.

Comment: Unless a user can have multiple avatars, can you overwrite the file you uploaded previously? (i.e so the URL starts to return the new file instead?)

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969981/how-to-replace-an-image-in-cloudinary-and-keep-the-same-url

Comment: @MukeshMaurya I have checked that one out actually, and I have the same problem regarding the caching of images. Looked it up on Cloudinary's site and they suggested to include a version in the url when requesting an image.